# How to prevent execution of serverside function using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, postback

I am trying to test for a textbox value.

*If the value matches my criteria do a javascript function*

**ELSE**

*do textchanged event in code behind.*

I have a jquery function that is triggered using javascript on change

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function test() {
  if ($('#<%= txt.ClientID%>').val() == '1') {
      return false;
    }
};
```

**ASP.NET**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="Server" AutoPostBack="true" onchange="test(this)" />
```

**VB.NET**

```
Protected Sub txt_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txt.TextChanged
...
End Sub
```

---

While debugging the function clearly returns false however the textchanged event still causes a postback.

**THE MARKUP RENDERS AS**

```
onchange="test(this);setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$Master$Content$txt\',\'\')', 0)"
```

**QUESTION**

### How can the textchanged event be restricted to only execute when certain client side criteria are met?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to return false inline of textbox as below:-

```
function test() {
    if ($('#<%= txt.ClientID%>').val() == '1') {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};


<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="Server" AutoPostBack="true" onchange="if(!test(this)) return false;" />
```

Comment: Your a genius ramby, this seems to have set me along the right track. I have been scratching my head on this one for a while. Any chance your could explain why this would work and my code will not? I am really intreagued.

Comment: return true/false in the js function is used to exit from the js function with value true/false so as per your code you can interpret onchange="false" which does not mean to stop the postback. but on the same place if you make it onchange="return false" then it will stop the postback.

so you can also avoid postback like onchange="return test();"